# How do I add two rows that say T^2 l and delta T^2 l without messing up the formatting

Tags: tables, tabularx

This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}           
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \sisetup{round-integer-to-decimal,
             round-mode=places,
             round-precision = 4,
             table-format= 1.4
             }
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { *{9}{X[c, si]} @{}},
             row{1}  = {guard, mode=math},
             row{2}  = {guard, mode=text},
             row{3-Z}= {rowsep=0pt},
             row{odd[3-Z]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                 }
    \toprule
l 
    &   \bar{t}_{10} 
        &   \Delta t_{10} 
            &   T 
                &   \Delta T 
                    &   l^2 
                        &   T^2 
                            &   \Delta T^2 
                                & T^2 l
                                    &   \sigma 
                                    \\
(\unit{\meter})
    &   (\unit{\second})
        &   (\unit{\second})
            &   (\unit{\second})
                &   (\unit{\second})
                    &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                        &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                            &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                                & (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                                    &   (\unit{\second})
                                        \\
        \midrule
0.450   & 15.41    & 0.1739    & 1.541 & 0.01739   & 0.2025    & 1.069     & 0.02412   & 0.1168    \\
0.400   & 14.84     & 0.3927   & 1.483 & 0.03927   & 0.1600    & 0.8810    & 0.04661   & 0.1916   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is what it produces:

[image]

how do I make it so that it says T^2 l and delta T^2 l along with everything else without messing up the formatting?

This is my data for T^2 l and delta T^2 l:

```
T^2 l:
1.069164057
0.880657854
0.761288073
0.620010716
0.502945492
0.381900226
-0.380525147
-0.507008082
-0.635167738
-0.741954159
-0.881032997
-1.068750692

delta T^2 l:
0.024118
0.0466089
0.067336822
0.007926943
0.038065585
0.012290147
-0.011572805
-0.00870475
-0.022310573
-0.048431619
-0.017714337
-0.030382095
```

This is an example of a table with that:

[image]

Comment: If you highlight your code and click `{}`, it will become nicely formatted.  It would also help to include the `\documentclass` and everything else so that we can copy and paste your code.  But I don't quite understand your question.  You already have `T^2 l` as the (next to?) last column in your example, and adding a `∆` is not that hard.  What have you tried?

Comment: so I'm trying to add one column that says T^2 l and one on the right of it that says delta T^2 l (as the final image). I understand how to put that, but when I do the spacing gets all weird. I have edited the post to show my document class. I've tried adding the data and everythng in but am just confused with the formatting.

Comment: Could you post your example with only the first two rows of data, but also with your attempt to include delta T^2 l?  I'm also a little confused about the column with sigma, but that's a separate question.

Comment: ok, so the column with sigma is the standard deviation, thats meant to go on the far right. Note that the units for l^2 and T^2 and delta T^2 are messed up, but ill fix that myself. Also the data that for T^2l in the picture i showed is supposed to go where sigma is. the data for T^2 l and delta T^2 l are both in the post. I have done the example with the first two rows of data now.

so just to clarify, the column where the data says 0.1168, 0.1916 and so on should go on the far right as that is the data for sigma (standard dev) the necessary data for T^2 l and delta T^2 l is in the post.

Comment: So the code you have posted does not include the data for T^2 l nor the data for delta T^2 l, and it doesn't include the headers T^2 l nor delta T^2 l.  You said you tried to put it in, but the spacing gets all weird.  That's the code that we need to see.  Does that attempt give any errors?  That would also be useful to report.

Comment: the data for T^2 l and delta T^2 l is in the post, not in the code. i will put the code for what I've done now.

Comment: @Tepeemm ok, ive doine that now, does it make more sense?

Comment: you have still not posted a example people can run to see the probem and test issues

Comment: "what I currently have" does not have `\Delta(T^2 l)`, so it cannot produce what you claim that it produces.

Comment: If you like to add two more columns (to my answer on your previous question), , you need to change `colspec = { *{9}{X[c, si]} @{}},` to `colspec = { *{11}{X[c, si]} @{}},`,  and then insert those two new columns where you like to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- just guessing what you after ...
- if you like to add two more columns (I suppose that before last column in original table from previous question), than you also need to change column specifications accordingly as I noted in my comment;
  `colspec = { *{9}{X[c, si]} @{}},` to `colspec = { *{11}{X[c, si]} @{}},`
- since you original table is already quite wide, for new table, that can be fit in width of text block, you need to reduce size of font used in table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}  % in real document remove `showframe` option!
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \sisetup{round-integer-to-decimal,
             round-mode=places,
             round-precision = 4,
             table-format= 1.4
             }
    \small                                      % <---
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { *{11}{X[c, si]} @{}},  % <---
             row{1}  = {guard, mode=math},
             row{2}  = {guard, mode=text},
             row{3-Z}= {rowsep=0pt},
             row{odd[3-Z]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                 }
    \toprule
l
    &   \bar{t}_{10}
        &   \Delta t_{10}
            &   T
                &   \Delta T
                    &   l^2
                        &   T^2
                            &   \Delta T^2
                                & T^2 l
                                    & \Delta T^2 l
                                        &   \sigma
                                            \\
(\unit{\meter})
    &   (\unit{\second})
        &   (\unit{\second})
            &   (\unit{\second})
                &   (\unit{\second})
                    &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                        &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                            &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                                & (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                                    &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                                        &   (\unit{\second})
                                            \\
        \midrule
0.450   & 15.41    & 0.1739    & 1.541 & 0.01739   & 0.2025    & 1.069     & 0.02412   
        & 1.069164057   & 0.024118  & 0.1168        \\
0.400   & 14.84     & 0.3927   & 1.483 & 0.03927   & 0.1600    & 0.8810    & 0.04661   
        & 0.880657854   & 0.1916    & 0.0466089     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines indicate /part/ of page layout)

- Is this what you after?
- I'm not know, which units use new columns. So, you need eventually to correct them.

**Edit:**

- Showed example on the end of question confuse what you after.
- What you like to tell with it? That new table has less columns as are produced by provided MWE (Minimal Working Example)?
- If this is the case, then please correct your question accordingly and remove this ambiguity.

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you

Comment: is it ok if i cite you or is there no need?

Comment: @NealBatra, what to cite= That I help you at design of table? No, it is not needed to do this ,,,, BTW, you may find it interesting: https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/